# Which documentation should I use to develop & test makefile based applications with Yocto?

Tags: cross-platform, toolchain, yocto, bitbake

I have installed Yocto, and successfully ran host-prepare.sh script. I want to know that, to develop makefile based applications, what to do next, should install toolchain or ADT or kernel & filesystem images? Is there any documentation which has step by step process?

Comment: What do you want to do? Build a rootfs with your appliction using OpenEmbedded (Yocto or is it Poky)? Or build your application outside of the build-system, using an SDK? And secondly, where does your host-prepare.sh come from? (Sure, I can search the web for host-prepare.sh, but wny should I? It's not coming from either OpenEmbedded or the Yocto Project).

Comment: I want to develop a makefile based application for p2020, I am using Yocto for that, Poky and OpenEmbedded are the parts of Yocto. I used QorIQ-SDK-V1.6XXXXX-yocto.iso to install Yocto, after which I found host-prepare.sh. What does I need to develop and test makefile based simple program?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) documentation, we may use 'Using Pre-Built Binaries and QEMU', but while doing this I am getting another error, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31981202/2706918).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases, one do not need to install Yocto at all, what is needed is just appropriate **toolchain** along with **filesystem image** to develop and test simple program with qemu (**runqemu** - which is emulator - a part of toolchain). These toolchains and filesystem images are available to download and ready to use. Refer '**Using Pre-Built Binaries and QEMU**' section in [this](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/yocto-project-qs/yocto-project-qs.html) documentation.