# Error while running poky-qemu: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found. How to solve this?

Tags: linker, qemu, toolchain, yocto, openembedded

I am using 32Bit Ubuntu 14.04, where newest version of libc6 is already installed. When I run **'poky-qemu qemuppc zImage-2.6.37-qemuppc-1.0.bin yocto-image-lsb-sdk-qemuppc-1.0.rootfs.ext3'**, I am getting following error:

```
    /opt/poky/1.0/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qemu-system-ppc: /opt/poky/1.0/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2)
```

Is this problem in toolchain or my host machine? How to solve this error?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: When I run **ldd --version** it shows **ldd (EGLIBC) 2.12.1**. Now the problem is that, how can I install required version of glibc at **/opt/poky/1.0/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/lib/**, which is created/used by toolchain. It's a known bug for **qemu** [Bug 2748], but I could not find any solution on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknowingly, I had used **wrong/old version** of kernel image and filesystem image. Using latest version which is 1.8, solved the problem.